# Error saving JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I have following JSON file:

```
weather = [ 
   {      
         "city": "Munich",
         "temp": {
              "temp_val": "30 deg",
              "temp_unit": "C"
          },
         "speed": {
              "speed_val": 7.31,
              "speed_unit": "m/s"
          }
   }
]
```

I am new to working with JSON files. I want to save this JSON file as weather.json.

But it gives following error:

> Expected value at 1:0 pointing to the first line of the file.

Comment: What's code you are using to save the json?

Comment: That's not valid JSON, for starters. If you removed the `weather = ` at the start, it would be. JSON does not involve variable definitions.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have `weather =` in your JSON file. JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation so anything other than a JavaScript Object won't work. You also can't have functions in there. Take a look at the [JSON official website](http://www.json.org/) to see what the format accepts

This should be correct:

```
[ 
   {      
         "city": "Munich",
         "temp": {
              "temp_val": "30 deg",
              "temp_unit": "C"
          },
         "speed": {
              "speed_val": 7.31,
              "speed_unit": "m/s"
          }
   }
]
```

You can then add this line in your javascript once you load the file into a string:

```
weather = JSON.parse(some_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are manipulating this file as if it was going to be rendered as JavaScript. This should only be plain text, no variable definitions. Just plain key value pairs. If you want to assign variable, set it to a .js file and render it in a browser.

You should look at an example file for JSON and model it. Remember that JSON is just plain text organized in a particular way.